# Sort values from two tables

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have one table with products and one table with purchases. 
I want to show a top 10 list of products and order the list by

1. Products that the current user has purchased
2. Sorted by product name

Here is a fiddle with example. Notice how it does a full scan of the product table

In this example the user has only purchased one product ('Product X'), so that product should be at the top in this list.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48e19/1

Any suggestions how I can improve this so that the query will be fast and does not scan the whole table?

I can change the database layout and/or indexes if that's needed.

**UPDATE**
The code below makes the query faster, but i'm still curious if it's possible to do this without having to have all these multiple queries.

```
;WITH purchased_products AS (
  SELECT ProductId FROM Purchases WHERE AccountId = @AccountId
)
SELECT top 10 * FROM (
  SELECT TOP 10 ProductId as Id FROM purchased_products
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM Products WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM purchased_products) ORDER BY Name
) t
```

Comment: You need to put pu.AccountId = @ACcountID in your where clause and not in your join condition. Then you will only get 1 row as you need.

Comment: I want a total of 10 products. Not only purchased products. But I want purchased products to be at the top of the list.

Comment: Your sort doesn't look exactly right to me, but I assume you've got it working.  Since the top 10 cuts the size of the table but the initial sort does not, it may be that the unioned subquery generates the most efficient sorted set.  Given the initial problem my answer is the most efficient 'simple' solution I can think of. You might try taking the ID out of the nonclustered index on the products table; that might cause the query compiler to recognize it better.

Comment: Note: tried changing the index on SQLFiddle, execution went down to 9ms.  In practice, most of this stuff should be fairly trivial as far as performance goes.

Comment: Ok, what kind of index did you add?

Comment: I didn't add an index on the SQLFiddle.  I removed the ID field from the nonclustered index on the Products table.  Because you're not including the ID in the query, it may not have any affect or get detected by the query compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem:

```
DECLARE @AccountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'F621080F-031E-4B8B-89F0-793DD9DFF8A2'

select top 10 prds.id, prds.name from Products prds 
LEFT JOIN Purchases pu ON prds.Id = pu.ProductId AND pu.AccountId = @AccountId
ORDER BY pu.ProductId desc, prds.Name desc
```

By changing the LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY around a little you've cut out the need to scan either entire table.

Comment: He wants the top ten products, not just the purchased ones.

Comment: He wants the products the current user has purchased. Since he hasnt bought 10. It should not show top ten. He has only purchased 1

Comment: He must also want the other 9 products sorted by ID, or he'd just do an inner join and sort it.  Using a left join implies he wants products the user has not bought.

Comment: That is not what he writes in his question. Look at no1

Comment: This seems to be a performance optimization and not an operation syntax question.-

Comment: I don't see how this change the query plan? When I try it in fiddle it also doesn't seem to help?

Comment: The SQLFiddle plan shows it doing only a 'topN' sort. I guess if it doesn't work this way you could UNION a top 10 of the first table sorted by name with an inner-joined table sorted by name, then take the re-sorted top 20, but that's a lot of code to write to convince yourself you're smarter than the SQL compiler.